# GridView not refreshing from SearchView query

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-arrayadapter, searchview

My main goal is to display a (Grid) list of Books ( referred as BookObjects in my code) with a query from a SearchView. My code actually parses JSON from URL using Google Books API.
The code I implemented modifies the http link from given query in searchBox.
(it uses ArrayList and a custom Adapter aswell as a custom Loader specifically built for BookObjects I implemented).

The problem I am facing is as it follows:

The first search goes well ( gridview inflates correctly from query word/s) yet when I retype keyworks in the searchBox , **my gridView never refreshes**. It stays with current items from first search.

My current code in main activity looks like this:

```
 public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<BookObject>> {
 public String http_link;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
    ...

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    final GridView booksListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridList);
    mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    booksListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

    mAdapter = new BookAdapter(UserActivity.mMainActivity, new ArrayList<BookObject>());
    final LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(
            new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    //check if device is connected to network
                    if (isNetworkConnected() == true) {
                        http_link = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + query + "&maxResults=15";

                        Log.d(http_link, "link is:");
                        Log.d(mInputText, "link is:");

                       //Tried them both and had no success
//                           mAdapter.clear();
//                           mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null, UserActivity.mMainActivity);

                        booksListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                    } else {
                        mEmptyStateTextView.setText("No internet connection found.");
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            }
    );

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

These are found in my custom BookObject Loader:

(posted them so you would understand what happens when I call the Loader)

```
@Override
public Loader<List<BookObject>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    // Create a new loader for the given URL
    return new BookLoader(this, http_link);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<BookObject>> loader, List<BookObject> books) {
    // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
    View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
    loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mAdapter.clear();


    mEmptyStateTextView.setText("No books found");

    // If there is a valid list of {@link BookObject}s, then add them to the adapter's
    // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
    if (books != null && !books.isEmpty()) {
        mAdapter.addAll(books);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<BookObject>> loader) {
    // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.
    mAdapter.clear();
}
```

This is the adapter class code:

```
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BookObject> {
public BookAdapter(Activity context , List<BookObject> books)
{
    super(context, 0 , books); // 2nd par is 0 because we inflate manually
}

@Override
public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent)
{
    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;

    if(listItemView == null) {

        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(

                R.layout.books_grid_list, parent, false);

    }

    BookObject currentBook = getItem(position);

    TextView TitleTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Title_text_view);
    TitleTextView.setText(currentBook.getTitle());

    TextView SubtitleTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Subtitle_text_view);
    SubtitleTextView.setText(currentBook.getSubtitle());

    TextView AuthorsTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Authors_text_view);
    AuthorsTextView.setText(currentBook.getAuthors());

    ImageView ThumbnailImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_image_id);
    Picasso.with(UserActivity.mMainActivity).load(currentBook.getImageURL()).into(ThumbnailImageView);

    return listItemView;
}
}
```

I searched online for  solution and I tried to add in onCreateOptionsMenu -> onQueryTextSubmit method different lines like:(one at a time obviously)

```
mAdapter.clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

*Can you please show me what am I mistaken?*

Refresher: my GridView never updates after first query search.

*Note*: I checked through Logs that the link (http_link) updates with the new query from the 2nd (3rd 4th.. etc) search.

Therefore the issue is with my GridView that won't update with new items.

I really can't figure  it out and any advice that would lead me to the correct path would be highly appreciated. (been struggling on it for 5-6 hours now)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to get searched result on clicking the search option or search items changing on type text dynamically

Comment: I think the app would save some resources by fetching the result on clicking the search option.(and it would be more practical for me). Therefore this is the option I want

Comment: can you show your code from adapter? There might be something wrong in it. Like you forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged` in your `BookAdapter.addAll()` method. Also put `Log` in `onLoadFinished` just to be sure that the data is coming from server.

Comment: @pskink I am trying to develop a larger project as a hobby and this "adapter filtering" as you call it is just a piece of the puzzle. Later on I will need the flexibility of custom Loader,Adapter, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think I found the problem. Its with the Loader. As from the documentation of the Loader [LoaderManager.onInitLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#initLoader(int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E)), If the loader is already created then it just uses the same loader and `onLoadFinished()` is called directly.
So in your `onQueryTextSubmit()` instead of calling `initLoader()` call `restartLoader()`

```
loaderManager.restartLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null, UserActivity.mMainActivity);
```

Comment: Now that you mentioned I checked the documentation aswell and you are correct. Your notice was spot-on and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much